# ms project c# connect document to task on project web

Tags: c#, ms-project

how to connect automaticly file ([screen1](http://zapodaj.net/b078eecedc996.png.html)) from document project with library on project web site [screen2](http://zapodaj.net/0aa97c8dfbd0b.png.html), if I want manually upload a file on libarry ?

What I need it:
I create a project, I have a template on my site, but I can't connect file from template with task on schedule.

Comment: ... ? Even the pictures don't really help.

Comment: If you create a new project, you create automaticly sharepoint web site and scheudle for project. I neet to connect task from scheudle to file on sharepoint website.